# For $1<m<n$, show that $G=\langle (1,2,\ldots,m),\,(1,2,\ldots,n)\rangle \subset S_n$ contains a $3$-cycle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

(I compose the permutations left-to-right)

By way of induction on $n$, suppose for all $l < n$ that if $1 < k < l$ then $\langle (1,\ldots,k),\,(1,\ldots,l)\rangle$ contains a $3$-cycle. There is nothing to show for the base case $l=3$. Consider that
$$(1,\ldots,n)(1,\ldots,m)^{-1} = (m,m+1,\ldots,n). $$
and
$$(1,\ldots,n-m+1) = (1,\ldots,n)^{m-1}(m,m+1,\ldots,n)(1,\ldots,n)^{1-m}, $$
so that $(1,\ldots,n-m+1)\in G$. If $m \neq n-m+1$, then either $1 <m < n-m+1 < n$ or $1 < n-m+1 < m < n$. In either of these cases, the induction hypothesis provides that $\langle(1,2,\ldots,m) (1,\ldots,n-m+1)\rangle$ contains a $3$-cycle, which then must also be contained in $G$. We now only have the case where $n = 2m-1$.

I can proceed no further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $(1,2, ... , n)(1,2, ..., m)^{-1}(1,2, ..., n)^{-1}(1, 2, ..., m)
=(1nm)$, left to right.